# How to hide controls in flow player

Tags: javascript, flash, flowplayer

```
<param 
name="flashVars" 
value="config={'playlist':['screenshot.jpg',
{'url':'video.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}"
/>
```

which config key = value, should I put to hide the controls in flowplayer?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<param name="flashVars" value="config={'plugins': {'controls': null}, 'playlist':['screenshot.jpg', {'url':'video.mp4','autoPlay':true,'control':null}]}" />
```

'control':null should be under config's plugin property

Answer (score 0):

According to http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/controlbar.html

Simply: 'control':null

So:

```
<param 
name="flashVars" 
value="config={'playlist':['screenshot.jpg',
{'url':'video.mp4','autoPlay':true,'control':null}]}"
/>
```

Comment: create a fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

```
$f().onLoad(function(){
    $f().getControls().hide(); 
})
```